# How to use replace for removing a specific string in js

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I have a string like below

```
<p class"font-size: 14px;text-align: justify;">Myeloid leukemia is a `cancer of the myeloid line of the blood cells. Put simple, it is when abnormal white blood cells build up in the bone marrow and interfere with the production of normal blood cells. Bone marrow over time is replaced with abnormal (cancer) cells, which leads to a drop in red blood cells, platelets, and normal white blood cells. As a result, patients suffering from myeloid leukemia can suffer from symptoms ranging from fatigue, bruising, bleeding, and an increase in the number of infections.</p><p class"font-size: 14px;text-align: justify;">There are two distinct types of <a href="https://www.xpertdox.com/disease-description/Leukemia" class"background-color: transparent;">myeloid leukemia</a>: acute myeloid leukemia (AML) and chronic myeloid leukemia (CML).</p><p class"font-size: 14px;text-align: justify;"><strong>How Leukemia Develops</strong></p><p class"font-size: 14px;text-align: justify;"><strong>Acute Myeloid Leukemia</strong></p><p class"font-size: 14px;text-align: justify;">This type of leukemia, also referred to as acute myelogenous leukemia, acute granulocytic leukemia, acute myeloblastic leukemia, or acute nonlymphocytic leukemia, is a cancer which grows quickly in the blood and bone marrow. Of all acute leukemia types, AML is the most common; it begins when a patient’s bone marrow produces cells which are not yet fully mature, called blasts. In normal circumstances, these cells would continue to develop and become white blood cells, but for those with AML, the cells do not mature and therefore cannot perform their job of fighting infection.</p><p class"font-size: 14px;text-align: justify;">Another possible problem for those with AML may be the production of irregular platelets and red blood cells by the bone marrow. These cells can rapidly overtake the number of properly functioning white and red blood cells and platelets necessary for a healthy body, making AML the more deadly of the two forms of myeloid leukemia.</p><p class"font-size: 14px;text-align: justify;"><strong>Chronic Myeloid Leukemia</strong></p>`
```

Here I want to replace all occurrences of class="" as empty i.e for example

```
 replace.('class"font-size: 14px;text-align: justify;','');
```

But here I have 4 class but i know only there are classes thet starts like this class=" and ends with ".So therefore how can i replace all my classes as empty so that,

appears as

Comment: You want to remove the whole class attribute and its value?

Comment: Hi Isac,yes class and its value.

Comment: You can use remove attribute function, check out this link
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp

Comment: how is this related to angular or node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `String.replace` with this regex:

```
str.replace(/class="[^"]*"/g,'class=""')
```

Note that this assumes you fix the 'class' attribute in HTML to include the equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery you can use this:

```
var string = '<p class"font-size: 14px;text-align: justify;">blah blah blah.......</p>';

/* this show only text without brackets and class name */
   var text = $(string).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var text = 'class="asdasd" class="123" class="zczxcz"'
text = text.replace(/"(.*?)"/g,'""')
console.log(text)
```